# jQuery getting ID of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal box in jQuery which I have created to display some embed code. **I want the script to take the `id` of the link that is clicked but I can't seem to get this working.**

Does anyone know how I can do that or why this may be happening?

My jQuery code is:

```
function generateCode() {
    var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id');
    if($('#embed input[name="comments"]:checked').length > 0 == true) {
        var comments = "&comments=1";
    } else {
        var comments = "";
    }
    $("#embedcode").html('<code>&lt;iframe src="embed.php?answerid=' + answerid + comments + '" width="550" height="' + $('#embed input[name="size"]').val() + '" frameborder="0"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</code>');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.openembed').click(function () {
        generateCode();
        var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id');
        $('#box').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('#embed').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('#box').hide()
    });
});
```

My mark-up is:

```
<a href="#" id="7830" class="openembed">Embed</a>
<a href="#" id="9999" class="openembed">Embed</a>
```

Comment: in the document.ready() change this line: `var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id');` to `var answerid = $(this).attr('id');`, should work then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$('.openembed')
```

returns an array of matched elements. Your should instead select only the clicked element.
`$('.openembed')` works correctly if you assing a `click` event to all elements that have this class. But on the other hand, you're unable do know which is clicked.

But fortunately in the body of handler function click you could call `$(this)`.

`$(this)` will return the current (and clicked element).

```
// var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id'); // Wrong
var answerid = $(this).attr('id');   // Correct
// Now you can call generateCode
generateCode(answerid);
```

Another error is the body of `generateCode` function. Here you should pass the id of selected element. This is the correct implementation.

```
function generateCode(answerid) {
    if($('#embed input[name="comments"]:checked').length > 0 == true) {
        var comments = "&comments=1";
    } else {
         var comments = "";
    }
    $("#embedcode").html('<iframe src="embed.php?answerid=' + answerid + comments + '" width="550" height="' + $('#embed input[name="size"]').val() + '"frameborder="0"></iframe>');
}
```

Here I have implemented your code with the correct behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/pSZZF/2/

Comment: In the body of function handler for the click event you should remove   `$('.openembed').attr('id');` and use `$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: You should move `generateCode` after `var answerid = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure to understand what's your problem now.

Comment: May be better if we switch in chat.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of referencing the `class`, which will grab all members of that class, you need to reference `$(this)` so you can get that unique link when it is clicked.

```
var answerid = $(this).prop('id');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $('.openembed').click(function () {
    generateCode();
    var answerid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#box').show();
    return false;
});
```

Use $(this). $('.openembed') refers to multiple links.

Comment: Heads up for adding a short explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id');
```

needs to be

```
var answerid = $(this).prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the id when the correct anchor is clicked and pass it into your generateCode function

```
$('.openembed').click(function () {
    var answerid = $(this).attr('id');
    generateCode(answerid)

    $('#box').show();
    return false;
});
```

Change your function

```
function generateCode(answerid) {
  // dont need this line anymore
  // var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are trying to fix the click() function, but your issue is actually with the generateCode function.

You need to pass the clicked element to the generateCode function:

```
$('.openembed').click(function () {
    generateCode(this);
```

And modify generateCode:

```
function generateCode(element) {
    var answerid = element.id;
```

Of course `var answerid = $('.openembed').attr('id');` within the click code isn't correct either, but it doesn't seem to do anything anyway.