# Bootstrap accordion - hold open/close after navigation away?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just installed an accordion / collapsible element and on the page, it is functioning correctly. However, when navigating away and back, the previous 'close' action of the collapse is not retained. It's still open when I return.

Is there a way to retain the previous action of the collapse?

```
<div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">MORE</button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
        <div class="row">
            Foo bar - Foo bar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply check the documentation right here: [Bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) how to collapse or not collapse your accordion.

```
$('#demo').collapse({
  toggle: false //you can simple untoggle your collapse on page load. 
})
```

There is many more you can do too like:

```
.collapse('toggle') //Toggles a collapsible element to shown or hidden.

.collapse('show') //Shows a collapsible element.

.collapse('hide') //Hides a collapsible element.
```

### Update

to save the current state of the dropdown, I will suggest you use Jquery.cookies to do so. [This is a similar question to yours and I named all the steps there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194484/bootstrap-toggle-nav-item-to-stay-open-after-click/30195176#comment48495540_30195176)

Comment: Thanks, Coding, the collapse/no collapse is working fine. Will 'toggle: false' hold the action as I asked?

Comment: don't you want to disable the collapse when the pages load?

Comment: I'd like to keep the collapse if the user did the action to collapse. That is what is not staying.

Comment: oh I see what you mean. i will implement it using the cookies method in jquery

Comment: @PatrickLightning check my post, I just updated my answer with the link you need for cookies method in JQuery

Comment: Appreciate you spelling it out there, Thanks